# How can we know why type of permission we are handling, when using registerForActivityResult, RequestPermission?

Tags: android

In API 31, the following 2 APIs are deprecated

1. `requestPermissions`
2. `onRequestPermissionsResult`

Based on https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting, we should start to use

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(new RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
        // In this callback, how can we know what type of permission we are dealing with?
        if (isGranted) {
        } else {
        }
    });
```

But, in the callback, how can we know what type of permission we are dealing with? If I call the launcher with

```
private void fun1() {
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
}

private void fun2() {
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
```

In `requestPermissionLauncher`'s callback, how can I know I am dealing with `RECORD_AUDIO` or `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to create different launcher for every job that I need.

That way you just have to check for the result in the callback.

For example:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> recordAudioLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(new RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
        if (isGranted) {
        } else {
        }
    });

private ActivityResultLauncher<String> readStorageLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(new RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
        if (isGranted) {
        } else {
        }
    });

private void fun1() {
    recordAudioLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
}

private void fun2() {
   readStorageLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I feel it is kind of weird we have to do it this way, because we already pass in what type of permission in the launch(...) function, I thought we should able to retrieve such a value in callback too.

Comment: Yeah but think of it as a more explicit approach